# Why Cypress gives success after second attempt?

Tags: cypress

In my Cypress tests, I create some data in before block and then my test script is run that locates in it block. I checked business side flow and it seems like there is no error about app side. I just want to understand that why my test's result is success after second attempt. Does Cypress has this kind of solution to handle an error maybe?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Cypress has the ability to automatically retry any failed tests.](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/test-retries#How-It-Works) I would check your Cypress configuration's value for `retries.openMode`.

Comment: Looking at the screen shot, I would surmise he is using openMode not runMode. But maybe the question is not "Have I configured retries?" but "Why does this test succeed after the second attempt?"

Comment: Yep, error on my part - updated!